# Can I use an Xbox controller with a Mac?

Tags: controllers, macos

Has anybody got any experience using an Xbox controller with a Mac? I know you can run the firmware on a PC. If not, cheap controller recommendations would be welcome!

Comment: That would be cool. Although I doubt it's possible. You have to install a driver to make it work and the mac clearly won't accept windows drivers.

Comment: It is possible, there is a third party driver for OS X. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used an Xbox controller with my Mac (I don't even own an Xbox), but [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2006/05/19/use-your-xbox-360-controller-with-your-mac/) says it works.

Comment: Looks promising! Will give it a go at the weekend and get back to you :)

Comment: I can vouch for the tattiebogle driver. I have used it with an wired arcade stick and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. There is a driver downloadable free at https://github.com/360Controller/360Controller, an updated version of the Tattieboggle driver mentioned in a comment above.
It is the de-facto standard for XBox 360/XBox One controllers on OS X.
Installing it it in your system will add a new pane to the System Preferences, where you can check and configure your controllers.

To install it, download the latest disk image from https://github.com/360Controller/360Controller/releases and open the installer inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you connect if with a cable. - you may need to install a driver if you want to use it wireless.